# How can i call an async action method using Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, hangfire

I am working on an asp.net mvc5 web application, and i installed the Hangfire :-

```
Install-Package Hangfire
```

after that i created a startup.css class as follow:-

```
public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {

   }
}
```

then inside my global.asax file i tried calling 2 action methods ; `Index ()` & `ScanServer()`, as follow:-

```
 HomeController h = new HomeController();
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() =>  h.Index(), Cron.Minutely);
        }
```

&

```
 RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() =>  h.ScanServer(*****), Cron.Minutely);
```

now when Hangfire tried calling the Index() action method which have the following definition :-

```
 public ActionResult Index()
```

i got this error:-

> JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. You must
>   set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API.

while when Hangfire tried calling the ScanServer() action method which is an async Task ,which have the following definition :-

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ScanServer(string tokenfrom)
```

i got this error:-

> Async methods are not supported. Please make them synchronous before
>   using them in background.

so can anyone advice how to fix these 2 issues ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

i wrote the following inside the Startup class:-

```
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ScanningFinal;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace ScanningFinal
{

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
           .UseSqlServerStorage("scanservice");
        }
    }
}
```

& here is the connection string:-

```
 <add name="scanservice"    connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=ScanningService;integrated security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

but i am still getting this error :-

> JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. You must
>   set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API.

Comment: Have you left the configuration method empty in the Startup class?

Comment: Hangfire has to have a database to store the jobs in. Make sure you read [the documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/index.html). See how it says `.UseSqlServer`? You need to do that, or use one of the other job storage databases listed in their documentation such as Redis or MongoDB.

Comment: @mason but can i force it to store the jobs on a text file , for example ? or it need to be a DB ?

Comment: @Tom yes i left them empty ,, i though i need them if i want to acces the dashboard ? and is this causing the problem for calling async action method also ?

Comment: You need *some sort* of job storage mechanism. It doesn't really matter what sort. But the thing is, there is no built in job storage provider for text files that I know of. So you'd have to implement that yourself, which is a large task. You're better off using one of the existing storage mechanisms. MongoDB was easy for me to set up and use, perhaps it will meet your needs too. Or if you have an existing SQL Server database, that would work too.

Comment: yes i have SQL server and my current system is using it  ,, but i do not want hangfire to use the same database used by my system,, so can i create a new database specifically for hangfire and define the connect string for it inside the startup.config ?

Comment: @johnG Yes, you can :)

Comment: @Tom but this might not work due to permissions. now the application pool user can only read & write to the database ,, but he can not create new tables ....

Comment: @johnG Code doesn't belong in comments. Put it in your queston.

Comment: @mason can you please check my edit, i provided the code ..

Comment: There's two places you can configure job storage, depending on whether you're doing OWIN or not. Read [the documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/index.html). Try moving your job storage configuration into Application_Start above where you add the job itself.

Comment: but i am using asp.net mvc5 and   yes i am using owin .. so that why i chose the second approach ..

Comment: Then move `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() =>  h.Index(), Cron.Minutely);` into the OWIN Startup method. Don't put them in different locations.

Comment: ok it worked well and it created the tables correctly , but not sure if i will face problem inside my live environment  due to lack of permission to create tables .. now if i face any permission issue,, can i manually create the tables ?

Comment: @johnG Just give the account that it's running as the correct permissions.

Comment: but due to security constraints and application pool will not have permission to create new tables .. so if i create the table manually will this works ? and will Hangfire use them  ?

Comment: How would Hangfire know whether it created them or whether something else created them? It wouldn't. So if you have the scripts to set up the DB for it, then go for it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure Hangfire within your Configuration method.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourApp.Startup))] // Change YourApp to your base namespace
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseHangfire(config => 
        {
            config.UseSqlServerStorage("NameOfConnectionStringKey"); // Other storage options are available
            config.UseDashboardPath("/hangfire");
            config.UseServer();
        });
    }
}
```

Basically your first issue is that you haven't configured Hangfire to use a database.  With the above solution, I'm telling hangfire to use SqlServer as the job storage, passing it the connectionString key that is defined in the web.config.  If you do not wish to use SQL Server, then you can use other storage options - I've had success with MongoDB in my projects.

I'm also then setting the path to the dashboard, so you can access the pretty UI in your browser.

You can also supply your chosen dependency injection here too.

As to your second question, are you able to alter your service method from async to a syncronous method?

Comment: yes i can alter my service from async to sync but i do not wan to do so ? as i want the action method to be async action method...

Comment: I'm almost positive that Hangfire will run the operation in async anyway, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: but i need to have the action method as async, because the same action method can be called manually by end users.. so in this case i need to create another version of the action method .. which will not be very reliable ... i mean i will end up having two versions of the action method async & sync !!! can u adivce ?

Comment: @johnG Why do you need to make another action method? Why not use use a method that calls the Task's Wait method?

Comment: @mason can you adivce more on this please ? not sure i got your point ? now i need asyn action because users can call the async method manually from their browsers, and hangfire does not allow calling async action method ,, can you adivce more on your suggestion ?

Comment: @johnG Async action methods return a Task. That Task has a [Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx) function. You can call that from synchronous code, thus using your async action method in a synchronous manner, satisfying Hangfire.

Comment: so you mean to write another action method as follow:-public ActionResult NormalScanServer(string tokenfrom, string FQDN)
        {
          ScanServer(tokenfrom,FQDN);
          return Content ("completed");
        }

Comment: @johnG No, you don't need action method. Just call the .Wait() function of the task that your async action method returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89312/discussion-between-john-g-and-mason).

Comment: @mason you mean to write the following :- RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => h.ScanServer(****).Wait(), Cron.Minutely);

Comment: @mason also i noted something now when i first run my application inside visual studio the ScanServer was called ,, but it never called again although i define it to run each minute... please do not tell me that hangfire will not fire unless there is any activity of the server ?

Comment: @johnG Yes, I do mean that. Hangfire can only run when the application is running. So if you need to run it constantly [read the directions](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html) for how to do that. You can check the Dashboard to see when it's executing.

Comment: @mason seems a lot of configuration ,, is there another way to force the hangfire to execute even is there is not an activity in the application ?

Comment: @johng think about it. How can hangfire execute if the application hosting it isn't even running?

Comment: @mason but what do u mean by the application hosting is not running ? now if i try to login to the application after 2 days of inactivity i can,, so the application will be running ,,, is this correct? inactivity of an application is different than the application is not running,,, is this correct? or i did not understand you well..

Comment: @johnG When it comes to ASP.NET, often times inactivity does mean the application literally stops. If you're running IIS on premises, then you have to follow the directions I linked to above in order to force Hangfire to constantly run. Or if you're hosting in Azure in a non-free instance, you can just set it to autorun. But normally after a certain period of inactivity (usually 20 minutes) IIS will unload the application, thus Hangfire wouldn't be able to execute.

Comment: @mason yes in my case i am running IIS on  premises

Comment: @johnG Then you can follow the directions I linked to above.

Comment: @mason thanks alot for the help ,. Now i am going to use IIS 7 with windows 2008 R2, so will these steps work ?  as it mentioned that these steps applies for IIS 7.5 or above ?

Comment: @johnG Please *read* the directions, as it specifically says what version of IIS ships with Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: ok the direction says the following "l, you can use the auto-start feature of IIS ≥ 7.5 shipped with Windows Server ≥ 2008 R2",, so in my case i have IIS 7.0 so does this means that i can not have my hangefire works  ???